# scheduling alarmmanager not working on reboot my phone

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, alarm, android-broadcastreceiver

It's toasting until I didn't restart my phone but after restarting broadcastreceiver2 doesn't receive and nothing happens.

I followed http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/how-to-start-an-application-at-device-bootup-in-android and many other but nothing happens.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.k2.alarmmanagerdemo">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name="com.k2.alarmmanagerdemo.MyBroadcastReceiver"
            android:enabled="true">
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.k2.alarmmanagerdemo.BroadCastRecevier2"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button b1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        b1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startAlert();
            }
        });
    }


    public void startAlert() {
        EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.time);
        int i = Integer.parseInt(text.getText().toString());
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                this.getApplicationContext(), 234324243, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis(),
                1000 * 5,pendingIntent);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm set in " + i + " seconds",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

**MyBroadcastReceiver.java**

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm...." + System.currentTimeMillis(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.i("Alarm.", "alarm called" + System.currentTimeMillis());    

    }
}
```

**BroadCastRecevier2.java**

```
public class BroadCastRecevier2 extends BroadcastReceiver {

    MainActivity activity = new MainActivity();
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


        activity.startAlert();
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.setClassName("com.k2.alarmmanagerdemo",
                    "com.k2.alarmmanagerdemo.MainActivity");
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(i);
            Toast.makeText(context, "BOOT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.i("myboot","boot compleated inside");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: on which device you are testing ?

Comment: Lyf flame 6 , emulator with oreo os, and on  nox player.

Answer (score 1):

Remove this line from your `<receiver>` declaration for `BroadcastReceiver2`:

```
android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"
```

That line in the `<receiver>` tag is telling the system that only packages which have this permission are allowed to send your class the `Intent`.  Its' likely confusing the system and preventing the `Intent` from being sent to your receiver.

You may also find [this article](http://hiqes.com/android-alarm-ins-outs/) helpful when learning about alarms and the boot complete receiver.

Comment: sir this is not working can you suggest more. The link  https://github.com/hiq-larryschiefer/myalarmapp.git gave me a project but that project not running on my system , problem:  on reboot app is not working.

Comment: You must launch the app one time before the `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast will be sent to it.